# How to narrow remapped types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to narrow the type of the property `response` in the code below, but it's ending up with the union type: `{ users: string[]; } | { user: string; }`. What am I missing?

```js
type ActionMap = {
  list: {
    response: { users: string[] };
    error?: number | null;
  };
  create: {
    response: { user: string };
  };
};

// Remapping keys to add the start, finish and failure suffixes to each action
type ActionMapWithStages<T> = {
  [Property in keyof T as
    | `${string & Property}-start`
    | `${string & Property}-finish`
    | `${string & Property}-failure`]: T[Property];
};

type Action<T> = ActionMapWithStages<T> extends infer U
  ? {
      type: keyof U;
      payload: U[keyof U];
    }
  : never;


let action: Action<ActionMap> = { type: 'list-start', payload: { response: { users: [] } } };

if (action.type === 'list-start') {
  console.log(action.payload.response.users) // Property 'users' does not exist on type '{ users: string[]; } | { user: string; }'.
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYFkCGYoF4oDeAUFFADaIDOwAXISaVAE4SVhqUR0FQCunTSnWpNEqAOYBtALpQAvgG4GpCEybImAfjqpeAWwBGqqAB8ousmSWlFDOC0zAu9Rs1btUnbnwHDgoiXlrIKJbIgB6cKgAJQg9bDAxcSgAawgQSihgZChMABM8rIALaGpMJmAAGigAMzEqItzUQprMRDJeFihKXhq6gA8snIhMOEbRpDQiIlBIWAQUDGwAdURgIoBlYExxVgAeABUAPjwXKEkABXVICpAoMVT05BqoA9zKZVMoAAMAEgIREkoAAyKBXZA3UByAC0ZQq30+Zj+AP8QNB4MhIBhdVQDQRriR-0BgXR11UUOhrXanQg32kdAOlzJt2kSjCs2g8EmqEOJ3wXMWWDAq3WWx2+2OUAg-SczUyYhqxgAqgxNGdXBy6GkQM8oErgq4wJgQGRkPk6ErJNrdUrWZ85AwdBAAG6qJREMgQYC5BZoOgCtB7ANLMB8whZcDOADkFGosO2FSj1SNJrNeW8LDYHGcPH4qiE51kcnkISIiBeAAoJosAHQcvC4fAxqjAePlYBRgCUZzgHGQnprpvEVd9qBrKdN+RrmY8nBrecEndCRCAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLvEew) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have much to do with key remapping; instead you want `Action<T>` to be a union of possible `type`/`payload` possibilities instead of a single type.  That is, you want to *distribute* `{type: K, payload: U[K]}` across the union `K`=`keyof U`, instead of just applying it directly.  A possible fix is shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wO57ym). Does that meet your needs? If so, ⚠ great, sniped by @wonderflame.  Well, if you want to see my answer written up let me know

Comment: Thank you both! Your solution meets exactly what I need, @jcalz